# How do I print a list vertically side by side?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, loops, python-2.x

This is my code so far:

```
def main():
    places=["Hawaii","Ohio","Tokyo","Korea"]
    print(places,"\n")
    for i in range(0,len(places[0])):
        print(places[0][i])
    for i in range(0,len(places[1])):
        print(places[1][i])
    for i in range(0,len(places[2])):
            print(places[2][i])
    for i in range(0,len(places[3])):
            print(places[3][i])

main()
```

I'm trying to print the 4 words vertically side by side

Comment: You’ll probably eventually want to do this with [`zip_longest`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.zip_longest)

Answer (score 4):

Shoutout out to @Ryan for the suggestion

```
from itertools import zip_longest

def main():
    for a, b, c, d in zip_longest(*["Hawaii", "Ohio", "Tokyo", "Korea"], fillvalue=" "):
        print(a, b, c, d)

main()
```

Output:

```
H O T K
a h o o
w i k r
a o y e
i   o a
i
```

Edit with the nested for loops:

```
def main2():
    places = ["Hawaii", "Ohio", "Tokyo", "Korea"]
    for i in range(6):
        for j in range(4):
            try:
                print(places[j][i], end=' ')
            except:
                print(' ', end=' ')
        print()
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's a general solution regardless of how many items you have. Some optimization could be made, this code is intended for maximum clarity.

```
places=["Hawaii","Ohio","Tokyo","Korea"]
#Find longest word
max_len = max([len(place) for place in places])
# Loop over words and pad them with spaces
for i, place in enumerate(places):
    if len(place) < max_len:
        places[i] = place.ljust(max_len)
# Print the words one letter at a time.
for i in range(max_len):
        print(" ".join([place[i] for place in places]))
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you need this?:

```
places=["Hawaii","Ohio","Tokyo","Korea"]
vertical_list = [i for place in places for i in list(place)]
for letter in vertical_list:
    print(letter)
```

Output:

```
H
a
w
a
i
i
O
h
i
o
T
o
k
y
o
K
o
r
e
a
```